# Bootstrap 4 form fields not aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am writing a signup form using Bootstrap 4. I can't get the form fields for user image and biography, to align with the rest of the form fields.

I have tweaked the CSS several ways, but can't get the visual effect I want, which is:

1. Biography and photo upload fields be same width as all form fields, and align horizontally
2. Photo field split into two equal width sections (a bit like first and last name fields), with uploaded image horizontally aligned in one field, and the button horizontally aligned in a second field.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #63738a;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.form-control {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #969fa4;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.form-control,
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.signup-form {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.signup-form h2 {
  color: #636363;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form h2:before,
.signup-form h2:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 30%;
  background: #d4d4d4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.signup-form h2:before {
  left: 0;
}

.signup-form h2:after {
  right: 0;
}

.signup-form .hint-text {
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form form {
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: #f2f3f7;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 30px;
}

.signup-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.signup-form input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.signup-form .btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width: 140px;
  outline: none !important;
}

.signup-form .row div:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.signup-form .row div:last-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.signup-form a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.signup-form a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.signup-form form a {
  color: #5cb85c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.signup-form form a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.img-profile {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.avatar .figure img {
  float: right;
  width: 64px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">
  <title>Bootstrap Simple Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="signup-form">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <h2>Create Account</h2>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="required"></div>
          <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="required"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="screenname" placeholder="Username" required="required">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group avatar">
        <div class="row">
          <figure class="figure col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="">
          </figure>
          <div class="form-inline col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="file" class="file-uploader pull-left">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default-alt pull-left">Update Image</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-bio" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Biography</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <textarea name="user-bio" id="user-bio" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Brief biography"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Create Account Now</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I fix the alignment issue in the form?

Comment: `col-xs-12` isn't valid in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: `.avatar .figure img` has a fixed width of 64px so it will break your layout if that container is smaller

Comment: `.col-6` to both `<figure>`holding the image and the `<div>`next to it. `max-width: 100%;` on the `<img>` instead of `width: 64px`  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dpqmyj3f/)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is usually to strip out all the custom margins and padding you've applied. They're usually not necessary with Bootstrap, and they tend to cause problems.

Then wrap the entire thing with a container and set a max-width on it:

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #63738a;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.form-control {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #969fa4;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.form-control,
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.signup-form {
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.signup-form h2 {
  color: #636363;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css"/>

<div class="container signup-form">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <h2>Create Account</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="required"></div>
        <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="required"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="screenname" placeholder="Username" required="required">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group avatar">
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="figure col col-md-2 col-sm-3">
          <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="">
        </figure>
        <div class="form-inline col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
          <input type="file" class="file-uploader pull-left">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default-alt pull-left">Update Image</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user-bio" class="control-label">Biography</label>
      <textarea name="user-bio" id="user-bio" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Brief biography"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Create Account Now</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the width and remove the float

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #63738a;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.form-control {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #969fa4;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.form-control,
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.signup-form {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.signup-form h2 {
  color: #636363;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form h2:before,
.signup-form h2:after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 30%;
  background: #d4d4d4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.signup-form h2:before {
  left: 0;
}

.signup-form h2:after {
  right: 0;
}

.signup-form .hint-text {
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup-form form {
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: #f2f3f7;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 30px;
}

.signup-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.signup-form input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.signup-form .btn {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-width: 140px;
  outline: none !important;
}

.signup-form .row div:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.signup-form .row div:last-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.signup-form a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.signup-form a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.signup-form form a {
  color: #5cb85c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.signup-form form a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.img-profile {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}
/* code  */

/* for image */
.avatar .figure img {
    width: 64px;
}

/* for choose file input */
.pull-left {
    float: left;
   width: 138px;
   margin-left: -26px;
    
}
/* for biography */
textarea.form-control {
    /* height: auto; */
    margin-left: -15px;
    width: 390px;
}
/* upload button */

.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
   margin-left: 38px;
padding-left: 22px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">
  <title>Bootstrap Simple Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="signup-form">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <h2>Create Account</h2>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="required"></div>
          <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="required"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="screenname" placeholder="Username" required="required">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group avatar">
        <div class="row">
          <figure class="figure col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" alt="">
          </figure>
          <div class="form-inline col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="file" class="file-uploader pull-left">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default-alt pull-left">Update Image</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-bio" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Biography</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <textarea name="user-bio" id="user-bio" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Brief biography"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Create Account Now</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

see the last few lines and run a snippet to view result